# How can I convert from Datetime to Milliseconds in Django?

Tags: python, json, django, database, datetime

I want to convert date (ex: 2016-09-20 22:00:00+00:00) to milliseconds. I will apply this block:

```
def get_calendar_events(request):

    user = request.user
    taken_course = Course.objects.get_enrollments(user=user)

    homework_list = []
    for course in taken_course:
        homework_list = course.get_homeworks()

    data_l = []
    for homework in homework_list:

    data_l.append({
            "id": user.id,
            "title": homework.title,
            "class": "event-important",
            "start": homework.start_date,  # Milliseconds
            "end": homework.end_date  # Milliseconds
        })

    data = {
        "success": 1,
        "result": [data_l]
    }
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

I need to edit "start" and "end" tags in data_l. Thank you.

Comment: Milliseconds since when?

Comment: you want to convert this `datetime` object to a timestamp?

Comment: I query the database with start_date and end_date in related homework model. And it returns dates. So start start_date @DanielRoseman

Comment: How did that answer my question?

Comment: I just want to convert like this (Wed Sep 21 2016 12:20:24) to (1474449624880 milliseconds). @dunder

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. @DanielRoseman

Comment: You can't just convert a date "to milliseconds". It's like asking "how many miles is London". You need to say where you're starting from.

Comment: It is a time difference, end -start, so you can just convert to ms

Comment: Okay, I got it. :) Since Jan 1, 1970. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python 3, you can use [`timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=re#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method to get the number seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970.

```
import datetime
d=datetime.datetime.now()
print d.timestamp()
# 1474450000.164866
```

This is assuming the `homework.start_date` field is a `datetime` object.